# Print list of lists in Python in specific order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this list:

```
vshape = [['0','1','1'],['1','0','1'],['1','1','0'],['1','0','1'],['0','1','1']]
```

I need to print out every item in specific order - 
one line of vshape[0][0], vshape[1][0], vshape[2][0], vshape[3][0], and vshape[4][0];
followed by line of vshape[0][1], vshape[1][1] ans so on...

Output should look like ('0's creating a V-shape):

```
01110
10101
11011
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've attempted first?

Comment: This is what i tried first: vshape=[['0','1','1'],
        ['1','0','1'],
        ['1','1','0'],
        ['1','0','1'],
        ['0','1','1']]
        


for i in vshape[0:4][0]:
    print i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
for r in zip(*vshape):
    print(''.join(r))

# 01110
# 10101
# 11011
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't familiar with zip function. I tried to achieve this by *for i in vshape[0:4][0]    print i*, but obviously it was the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2):

```
vshape = [['0','1','1'],['1','0','1'],['1','1','0'],['1','0','1'], ['0','1','1']]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(5):
        print (vshape[j][i], end=' ')
    print()
```

> *This is one of my most used methods to print out patterns. In this, I use two nested for loops.*

Answer (score 0):

perhaps easier to understand with transpose, using numpy.

```
for r in np.array(vshape).T:
    print(''.join(r))
```